# What is the problem with µ in verbatim and verb commands?

Tags: verbatim

The following code results in error and µ is missing from the output in pdflatex. The same problem recurs when the verbatim environment is replaced with `\verb|µ|`.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \begin{document}
  text
 \begin{verbatim}
 µ
 \end{verbatim}
 \end{document}
```

This is independent of font encoding and input incoding since there aren't any problems  except again with µ when I use  either of the two options below.

```
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
  \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}                            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Which TeX distribution and which vintage of pdfLaTeX do you employ? I cannot replicate the issue you say you're experiencing a MacBook Air, MacOS 10.15.5 "Catalina", and TeXLive2020 with all updates installed. Specifically, I get a monospaced `μ` inside the verbatim environment and as the output of `\verb|µ|`.

Comment: @Mico The distribution is Miktex 2.9.6850-x64. I don't know about the vintage of pdflatex, the executable comes from the distribution.

Comment: I have no problems on miktex. I have MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit and LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5.

Comment: Thanks. Your MikTeX distribution may be several years old by now. (The current version is 2.9.7440.) If you open the log file (`\jobname.log`), on ca line 6 or 7 you should find something like `LaTeX2e <date> [additional information]`. What do you find for the date and possibly additional information?

Comment: @Mico pdflatex, Version .3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.96880 64-bit)
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>

Comment: @LPH - Since Ulrike Fischer has commented that she doesn't experience the issues you've experienced on her fully-up-to-date version of MikTeX, do see if updating your MikTeX distribution will solve the issue at hand.

Comment: @Mico I believe that is the first thing to try. Thanks for the help.